# given 2-d array of 0/1, find min row to be deleted so that n can't be created by OR of any rows

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across this interview question today, details are as follows:

you are given a 2 d array of 0's and 1's:

```
arr = [[0,1,0,1],\\binary rep of 5
       [1,0,0,0],\\binary rep of 8
       [0,1,1,1],\\binary rep of 7
       [0,0,0,1]]\\binary rep of 1
```

Given a number N lets say 9. If we remove [1,0,0,0] we wouldn't be able to create 9 by rest of the numbers. So the answer would be count = 1 and element(s) = [1,0,0,0]

The solution I have is:

1. Create a new 0/1 1-d array of size 4(length of each element in our case)
2. sum all the 1's if the bit at that position is 1, if bit at that position is zero we'll store "n - (1's count)". e.g. 9's binary representation is [1,0,0,1] hence new array would be:

   ```
   [1(total 1's in first index),
    2(total 0's in second),
    3(total 0's in 3rd index),
    3(total 1's in 4th)]
   ```
3. Here we can remove the element where 1 is present in first index. i.e. [1,0,0,0]

I have a feeling that this approach is wrong, and looking out for some modifications to make this right or any pointers if this approach is entirely wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "if we remove [1, 1, 1, 0]", there's no such element in you array

Comment: What operations may be used to get N from the list of input numbers?

Comment: @Rubens we can only use OR operators.

Comment: @diwakarb I replaced another occurence of [1,1,1,0] by [1,0,0,0] in your post.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot Step 0: discard every row that has a 1 where N has a 0. Your algorithm is otherwise correct, because none of the discarded rows can be part of an OR equaling N, and the OR of all subsets of remaining rows is not N if and only if the OR of everything is not N, which is the case if and only if some column is 0 in the OR when it should be 1, which is accomplished if and only if all rows with a 1 in that column are deleted.

Comment: maybe I didn't got your answer correctly, but we need to remove elements so that we "cannot" create N out of remaining elements.

Comment: @diwakarb I flipped the if and only ifs around by accident